# Issue with throughput controller

Tags: jmeter

my thread count is 100 and iteration count is 100 .50 users are registred users and 50 users are guest users.

1. home page -5%: This page should run for 5 %  total hit of both guest and logged in user irrespctive of user type.
2. Login page- 50% : This page run for 50% of total hit.
3. Search page 20%- This page should run for 20 % total hit- This can be run for guest as well as logged in user.
4. product page 15%- this page run for 15 % total hit-This can be run for guest as well as logged in user and this prequest is using parameters from search page(3rd request)
5. Add to cart 10%- This page should run for 10% of total hit- For performing this request i need to make sure that user is already logged in user and parameters are captured from search page reques(3 rd request)

I wan to create test plan for the above condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me, the question itself is not fully understandable.

As it not possible in single Thread Group to achieve the requirements, Following is the Test Plan you can try out to achieve the dependencies along with the percentage of distribution. `This is NOT a correct solution but I claim it as a probable solution. You can customize as per your needs`.

```
Test plan
...Thread Group (configure 100 users)
......HTTP Cookie Manager
......Throughput Controller (by percentage throughput - 5%, uncheck Per User checkbox)
.........Home Page (Transaction Controller)
......Throughput Controller (by percentage throughput- 20%, uncheck Per User checkbox)
............Search Page (Transaction Controller)
......Throughput Controller (by percentage throughput- 15%, uncheck Per User checkbox)
............Product Page (Transaction Controller)
......Throughput Controller (by percentage throughput- 50%, uncheck Per User checkbox)
.........Login page (Transaction Controller)
............Login Request (HTTP Sampler)
.........Throughput Controller (by percentage throughput- 20%, uncheck Per User checkbox)    
............AddToCart (Transaction Controller)
......Aggregate Report
```

Important Notes:

1. Added `Throughput Controllers` as a `parent of Transaction Controllers` to control the percentages. Uncheck `Per User` checkbox.
2. `Transaction Controller` contains the HTTP Samplers. eg: Login Transaction contains all the HTTP Samplers that are responsible for Login operation.
3. Add `Aggregate Report` listener under Thread Group, to capture all the request results.

Image reference:
[image]

Comment: Please share your requirements clearly, so that I can give a better Test Plan.

Comment: Thanks a lot Naveen, can you please look in to the question now.

Comment: Not necessary, my aim is to  achieve the behavior

Comment: updated the answer. please try and let me know if it solves the puzzle.

Comment: uncheck `Per User` checkbox in all Throughput Controllers

Comment: percentage wise this test is giving proper result, but there is some issue with the test suite.

Comment: did not understand. what is test suite? what is the issue? please update the question with necessary details

Comment: percentage wise this test is giving proper result, but there is some issue with the test suite. 1. I am using regex inside the search page result, that i am using as parameter for product display. Since no response found in the view results tree response this cannot be fulfilled 2. most of the time product page request getting fired before search page request

Comment: updated the image in the answer. used nested Throughput Controller and reordered the transaction as follows Login page -> Search page -> Products Page -> Add to cart page. refer the image only for the updated test plan.

Comment: Now the search page will run for guest users also?. What i understood from the image, search page and product page won't run for guest users .is that correct?I want to make it run for guest users also, not all my users is going to login.

Comment: No. they will run for logged in users only. What is the difference b/w sending/hitting search page and products page when we send with login and without login?? If you want to simulate both. Then create one more threadgroup additional to existing and add only search page and products page which will be hit only for guest users. Distribute the users accordingly.

Comment: Idea behind this requirement is to stimulate the exact behavior of user(guest user will hit search or product page without login). 
Right now product page is not working with the above test plan, it is expecting parameter from search result(this parameter is extracted from search result using regex)
And product page wont run 15 % of total hit it will just hit only 15 % of search page hit.Do we have any idea to make product page to hit 15 % of total hit

Comment: I forgot to tell u. Keep the percentages as follows to achieve  Search page - 40%, product page - 75%, addtocart - 66% and try to achieve the percentage distribution as mentioned in the question. Related to regex, what is the issue? In the test plan, product page will be executed only after search page. Pls share the details on reg ex extractor how u using. Update the question with all details.

Comment: Translation controllers doesn't have any response data it seems.So regex is not working. Do we have any way to enable the response data for transaction controllers?

Comment: It won't. you have to keep the reg ex extractor as a child to the HTTP sampler (login request/search request) in which the response contains.

Comment: Hi Naveen, I am trying to implement step-up thread group on the above suite. Will the through put controller will produce the result based on the step -up group?

Comment: NO. setup Thread threads are not related to actual Thread Group. see here for more details http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#setUp_Thread_Group. If you keep Throughput controller, then it is applicable to only `setUp ThreadGroup`

Comment: Hi Naveen, is it possible show only the http request in result view listener?. Right now my jenkins graph shows the transaction controller also as URI . I want show only actual requests.